# Converting Windows CE Forms to .Net Core

Tags: forms, winforms, asp.net-core, windows-ce, .net-assembly

Is there a solution currently help convert the targeted member "System.Windows.Forms.Control" in windows CE to .Net Core?

Assembly: "Device.WindowsCE.Forms.NET46"

Id' rather not have to rewrite all the areas when I'm using the assembly if there is a conversion tool or something that can help this change become a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing currently that exists to do this functionality, we will be doing it ourselves manually.

Comment: Hi @obizuses, are you running .NET core on Windows CE somehow?  Thanks.